# I am trying to get values from client.users.fetch(user id) but it just isnt working

Tags: discord.js

my code:

```
if(message.content == prefix + "dev"){
        const owner = client.users.fetch('462223589043863562');
        console.log(owner.user);
        console.log(owner.id);
        console.log(owner);

 message.channel.send(`eggy is the dev of this chad ass bot. Discord: ${owner}`);
```

logs:

```
undefined
undefined
Promise {
  User {
    id: '462223589043863562',
    system: false,
    locale: null,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 64 },
    username: 'eggyy',
    bot: false,
    discriminator: '0001',
    avatar: 'a_de18cc5553a2fd2e5fbd3d3e3491595b',
    lastMessageID: '865041520075735040',
    lastMessageChannelID: '864827452063875125'
  }
}
```

Also, when doing owner.Promise.User.user it gives an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<client>.users.fetch()` returns a promise which you can handle simply by using `await`.  Therefore, in order to resolve it, you can just replace your current `owner` definition with `const owner = client.users.fetch('462223589043863562');`.

However, if you are going to use `await`, you must make your present function `async` (e.g. `client.on('message', async message => {})`.

Comment: You can also use [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) which doesn’t require async, and also waits for the value before running.